# Woocommerce Related Products - show products in price interval

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to modify related.php in order to randomly show any 3 products from the shop that has a price in the range of plus/minus 100.

I'm using ACF fields and Woocommerce 3.2.
The problem is that although the products are selected correctly, their price is not displayed.  Instead, the price of the reference product is displayed for all 3 products.

Here is the code (price_obj is the ACF field for price):

```
global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());

$price_product = get_field('price_obj',get_the_ID());


$args1=array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post__not_in'      => array( $product->get_id() )
);

$products_in_range = array();

$my_query = new wp_query($args1);


if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $val = count($my_query->get_posts());
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');

        $price = get_field('price_obj');
        $id = get_the_ID();

        if ((($price_product-100) <= $price) && ($price <= ($price_product+100))){
            array_push($products_in_range,$id);
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();

$rand_products = array_rand($products_in_range, 3);

?>

<?php if ($rand_products){ ?>
<div class="related products">

    <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <ul class="products">
        <?php
            foreach ($rand_products as $prod){
                $title = get_the_title($products_in_range[$prod]);
                $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($products_in_range[$prod]), 'large');
                $link = get_permalink($products_in_range[$prod]);
                $product_prod = new WC_Product($products_in_range[$prod]);
                $price = wc_price($product->get_price());
        ?>
        <li class="product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">
                <span class="et_shop_image">
                    <img width="400" height="400"
                        src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>"
                        class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image"
                        alt=""
                        title="">
                    <span class="et_overlay"></span>
                </span>
                <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                        <?php echo $price; ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: get_filed() can take three parameters. the id of the field, the post id, and the format value, just add the post id to the call like such, $price = get_field('price_obj', get_the_ID() ); or if you get the id first then you can just use get_field('price_obj', $id );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_field()` can take three parameters. The first one is mandatory but the last 2 are optional.

```
get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);
```

Where the `$selector` is the name of the field.The `$post_id` is self explanatory, **but is defaulted to the current post** and the `$format_value` decides whether you want to apply formatting logic.

<del>Because you are calling the function via `get_field('price_obj')` and omitting the ID of the post you want it is defaulting to the current post in this case the post of the main item.</del>

This is wrong, because you were inside the WordPress loop the right object was being saved into `$price`.

As you mentioned below, when you went to access the object via

`$price = wc_price($product->get_price());`

You were accessing the `$product` object, which is the main item. But your sub-product were stored in $product_prod, so to access it's price you had to change your code to

```
$price = wc_price($product_prod->get_price());
```

Comment: It's not working. I changed:
`$price = get_field('price_obj');
        $id = get_the_ID();`
to
`$id = get_the_ID();
$price = get_field( 'price_obj' , $id);`

still the same. The problem, as I see it is here: 

`$price = wc_price($product->get_price());`

Comment: you reference the individual products as prod, did you try $price = wc_price($prod->get_price());

Comment: tried already... it throws me an error...

Title, image, link... is working, the price... I don't manage to understand what is wrong...

Comment: Solved...
`$price = wc_price($product_prod->get_price());`